# MissingMethodException during groovy recursive fibonacci function

Tags: recursion, groovy

I keep getting a missing method exception when I try to run a groovy script with a recursive function call.

If this is my script content:

```
def factorial = { n ->
  if (n == 0) 1 
  else n * factorial(n - 1)
}

factorial(4)
```

And it's been saved in a file called fib.groovy, running the script by calling groovy fib.groovy results in this:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
fib.factorial() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer)
```

Can someone point out any syntax errors I'm missing that is causing the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closure has to be defined before its implementation, for the recursive call to work.

```
def factorial 

factorial = { n ->
  if (n == 0) 1 
  else n * factorial(n - 1)
}

factorial(4)
```